# Error with multiplying char with a number and add with char ( Big Java Ex 6.2)

Tags: java

Currently going through an exercise in my book, but i'm stuck ( I havent learned arrays yet, this chapter is on loops nested loops and for loops)

The first part of the problem is to take a credit card number and then sum every other number backwards

Consider `4358 9795`, which should output the sum `5+7+8 + 3 = 23`.

Heres my solution which isn't working

```
class Checkit{
    private String creditNum;
    private int sum;
    public Checkit(String creditNum)
    {
        this.creditNum = creditNum;
        sum = 0;
    }

    public int getSum()
    {
        for (int i = creditNum.length() ; i > 0 ; i--)
        {
            char ch = creditNum.charAt(i-1);
            if(i%2 == 1 )
            {
                sum+=ch;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }


    }


public class test{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Checkit sampleNumber = new Checkit("4358 9795");
        System.out.println(sampleNumber.getSum());
    }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure whats wrong with my logic. ch is taking all of the values of my credit card number 5,7,8,3. But for some reason the sum is messing up.

**BONUS PART**

Take Each number that wasn't added and double it, so `9+9 + 5 + 4`, double each of those terms ( that becomes `18 + 18 + 10 + 8`), and then get the sum of `1 + 8 + 1 + 8 + 1 + 0 + 8`.

I tried the bonus part, but for some reason every time I get `9, 9, 5,4` and times that `char` value by `2`, I get letters. I don't think I can multiply chars by `integers`, so should I do conversions? Note I didn't learn `arrays` yet

**NEW CODE**

```
class Checkit {
    private String creditCardNum;
    private int sum;

    public Checkit(String creditCardNum) {
        sum = 0;
        this.creditCardNum = creditCardNum;
    }

    public int getSum() {
        creditCardNum = creditCardNum.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        for (int i = creditCardNum.length(); i > 0; i--) {
            char ch = creditCardNum.charAt(i - 1);
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                sum += Character.getNumericValue(ch);

            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public int doubleDigitSum() {
        sum = 0;
        creditCardNum = creditCardNum.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        for (int i = creditCardNum.length(); i > 0; i--) {

            char ch = creditCardNum.charAt(i - 1);
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                int newChar = Character.getNumericValue(ch) * 2;
                String newCharString = Integer.toString(newChar);
                for (int j = 0; j < newCharString.length(); j++) {
                    char sumThis = newCharString.charAt(j);
                    sum += Character.getNumericValue(sumThis);
                }


            }

        }
        return sum;

    }
}

public class DataSet{
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Checkit data = new Checkit("4358 9795");
        System.out.println(data.getSum());
        System.out.println(data.doubleDigitSum());
    }
}
```

Comment: The char `'4'` is not the same as the number `4`. Its value is the value of the Unicode encoding used to represent it. You should subtract `'0'` from each char before doing any math with it, to convert it to the correct numeric value.

Comment: `char ch` look at the value of that variable.

Comment: Ok. I will try when I get home thanks all. But why -2? I actually tried to research before asking and I couldn't find the answer in my textbook. Plus it was actually giving me a sum, it's just he sum was a huge number

Comment: nota: this is not going to work anyway, because `if(i%2 == 1 )` does not consider the fact that there is a space in your number.

Comment: njzk2 is right, your code won't work if the string `creditNum` has an odd number of characters, because then you'll start summing from the second to last character as opposed to the last character.

Comment: Your right! I'm going to try adding an extra && and check if it's a space with .equals. if it is it shouldn't add to the sum that's what I remember doin from last chapter. Thanks

Comment: Anytime! If you found my answer helpful then don't forget to mark it as accepted. Good luck coding!

Comment: Just got home. I was wondering, can I use ch.equals(" "), I remember my book saying .equals is for comparing strings. Basically I want to check if theres a space, if there is just dont do anything

Comment: Would String.valueOf(ch)!=" " work?

Comment: It will work but the more conventional way is ch != ' '. The difference is single quotes as opposed to double.

Comment: Why does single quotes work, but double doesent? Arent they the same?

Comment: No in java, char is signified by single quotes while string is defined by double quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding `char` values rather than int values. Replace `sum+=ch;` with

```
sum += ch - '0';
```

The reason why this works as opposed to the original solution is that when you're adding `char` values to an `int` value, the `char` is converted to a decimal via its ASCII value. For example, '5' has a ASCII dec value of 53. However, '5' - '0' equals 5. More on these ASCII values can be found here, http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: This works, but it's very hard to read. I'd suggest especially a new programmer use the Character function for this instead because it's explicit and clear what it's doing.

Comment: @James I understand. I just like putting up both solutions because some people may prefer one over the other. Thank you for your input though, very appreciated.

Comment: Fair! It's good to have multiple solutions here, especially if other people look at this later.

Comment: Hi just got home. I want to skip cases with spaces so I tried but %% ch!=" ", but it won't let me do this. is there anything like .getNumericValue for strings?

Comment: I think I found it "String.valueOf(ch)!=" ""

Comment: @cresjoy when comparing char, use the == or != sign. For example, ch != ' '. Remember single not double quotes. Your way works but my way is more conventional. Check it out for yourself.

Comment: Hmm but now it wont add the 3 value, I just get a sum of 20, since if you do i%2, the spaces in between get counted for in the i's they just don't add in the sum but this messed up the i value for modulus

Comment: Is there a way to remove the spaces all together? I just wanted to keep them in the input, since the book said to have a space in between

Comment: I updated my code, as you can see, due to the spaces in between the modulus operator is getting messed up and not adding every other. Only way I can think of solving this is to remove all spaces in the first place before we start looping

Comment: @cresjoy if you want to get rid of spaces, use the split method. The split method will return all elements of a string separated by a specified character (s) placed into an array

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Lol the solution in the book was a simple while loop. They divided by 10 to get the rightmost digit, and divided by 100 to get the ones after. Pretty cool thought, I like my way though it seems ok. Ill give split a shot

Comment: @cresjoy anytime, dont forget to mark my answer as accepted if you found it helpful. Good luck coding!

Comment: It works now!!!! I learned alot of casting manipulation from this. Thanks alot!! Feels good to solve it! Posted the solution in my question at the bottom if anyone else wants to see

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are not converting the char to an integer:

```
public int getSum()
    {
        for (int i = creditNum.length() ; i > 0 ; i--)
        {
            char ch = creditNum.charAt(i-1);
            if(i%2 == 1 )
            {
                sum+=ch;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Fun fact that's causing your error - chars are numbers! They're simply a number that represents the ascii character code of the letter. So when you add them to a sum, Java is OK with that and just adds the corresponding number for the char '8' for example, which is 56.

To make your code work, you need to properly convert to an integer:

```
public int getSum()
    {
        for (int i = creditNum.length() ; i > 0 ; i--)
        {
            char ch = creditNum.charAt(i-1);
            if(i%2 == 1)
            {
                sum+=Character.getNumericValue(ch);
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = creditNum.length() ; i > 0 ; i--)     {
    char ch = creditNum.charAt(i-1);
```

First iteration thru loop gets IndexOutOfBounds exception. And then you never check the initial character of the credit card number, since your termination criterion is ( i > 0 ), not (i >= 0)

And why not just use i -= 2 for the increment instead of the if-check?